# Which statistical test should I use to compare two models (multiple runs) on the same (big) dataset?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test

I want to compare the performance of two stocastic models on the same datasets (>10k samples).

To this end, I run 5 runs for each model (different seed) and I can compute the mean and std for each model.
If I now want to run a statistical test to assess the significance of the difference in their performance, is a corrected paired t-test appropriate?  Does it depend on the metric (e.g., accuracy vs f1)? What should I consider?

E.g, assume I have model A and model B and I run them 5 times each on dataset D (50K samples).
Once averaged the 5 runs, I get:
Model A: Acc mean 90.10, std 5
Model B: Acc mean 92.4, std 7

Is there a test I could use in this case? Would [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_rel.html) one be appropriate? Why?

Comment: Did you decide on a test?